# ow can I use pandas to get the same group by result like mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

[image: This is mysql table]

I query it using "select * from link05m group by class, time", the result looks like:
[image: result from mysql]

How can I get exactly the same result using pandas?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/test?charset=utf8')

link05m = pd.read_sql_query("select * from link05m where time ='2015-12-24 10:00:00'", conn)

grpResult = link05m.groupby(['time', 'class']) 

for r, g in grpResult:
    print g  # each g is make up of serveral Dataframes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have aggregation to perform (ie : each pair of time, class is unique), then you don't need to do a pandas groupby. You should try :

```
link05m = pd.read_sql_query("select * from link05m where time ='2015-12-24 10:00:00'", conn)

Result = link05m.set_index(['time', 'class'])
```